# Оптимизация кода с replace()

Tags: java, алгоритм, регулярные-выражения, строки, kotlin

Есть небольшая програма по форматированию строки с использованием регулярного выражения. В коде присутствует множесвенное использование функции `replace()`, для нахождения хаотичных пробелов перед\после разделительными знаками и замены на правильные:

```
buffer = this.replace("\s*,\s*", ", ")
buffer = buffer.replace("\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*", ". ")
buffer = buffer.replace("\\s*\\.{3}\\s*", "... ")
buffer = buffer.replace("\\s*'\\s*", "'")
```

где `this` это строка. Насколько я понял в данном случае програма 4 раза перебирает строку и заменяет удовлетворяемые регулярное выражение символы, что уже есть не хорошо.

1) Уместно ли использовать такой подход для форматирования строки?

2) Есть ли относительно простой способ замены символов в одну итерацию?

Answer (score 2):

У вас каждое действие - уникальное. Если бы все регулярные выражения были ради одного результата (например всё менять на точку) - тогда их можно было бы свести в одно выражение.

Вынесете форматирование строки в отдельный класс.

```
static class MyUtils{
        public static String normalizeString(String src){
            src = src.replace("\\s*,\\s*", ", ");
            src = src.replace("\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*", ". ");
            src = src.replace("\\s*\\.{3}\\s*", "... ");
            src = src.replace("\\s*'\\s*", "'");
            return src;
        }
}
```

и пользуйтесь:

```
buffer=MyUtils.normalizeString(this);
```

Comment: И в резудьтате у вас выйдет 4 итерации перебора текста. Вы не поняли суть вопроса.

Comment: Я понимаю что вы хотите сказать, и ответил что каждое действие - уникальное. В каждом действии - нужно заменить на разную последовательность символов (запятая, многоточие и т.д.). Даже если вы напишете buffer = this.replace("\s*,\s*", ", ").replace("\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*", ". ").replace("\\s*\\.{3}\\s*", "... ").replace("\\s*'\\s*", "'") ...фактически это те же самые четыре уникальных операции. Засунуть всё в одно регулярное выражение нет смысла.